# Bootstrap Dropdown background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a dropdown list in the navbar that matches the style of the rest of the navbar.  I have not overwritten any of the bootstrap classes to my knowledge and I am wondering if there are any classes that have the same styling for a dropdown list.

I have been looking through other articles and most seem to just use a random class and it works correctly.  I tried to make a custom CSS class for it but I was unable to successfully match the header.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Management
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Management")">Statistics</a>
       <br />
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Production")">Production Lines</a>
       <br />
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Announcement")">Announcements</a>
       <br />
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Index", "TestStation")">Test Stations</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

When creating a dropdown list, is there a special class to use that matches the navbar or do I have to create a custom one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dropdown-item background color in bootstrap is white and if you want change it you can change it in your page style. you can add this code to your head tag:

```
.dropdown-item{
background-color: #2e89e5;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked to some degree.  It changed the background of the TEXT but not the rest of the dropdown.  I am wondering if you know how to change the color of the rest of the background as well.

Comment: yes. there are a simple way to change color of every style of bootstrap pages. in your browser right click on your tag and click Inspect element and then in right hand in style layout change color of every element you need then create a style such as .dropdown-item and paste code from inspector to your code.

Comment: Thanks!  I was about to do some inline CSS to set the background color of the menu, it wouldn't if I put it in the header for some reason.  I then had to do more inline CSS for each link to set their color to white.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your nav-bar uses the primary color you can give the dropdown the `bg-primary` class to give it the primary color background (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color)

It's possible your going to have to assign this class to all the `ul` items individually

Comment: ```<a class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Management")">Statistics</a>```  I tried to a fix based on the link provided.  Similar to Majid's suggestion it only changed the background of the TEXT not the whole dropdown.  Could you provide an example in case I implemented what was in the link incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Change the styling of the `.dropdown-menu` class in your style sheet in bootstrap 4.1.3.